# Failed to read row 0, column 4 from, Cursor Databasa

Tags: java, android, exception, cursor

I have problem with this exception:

> Failed to read row 0, column 4 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 4 columns.

```
public ArrayList<Nota> listNote(){
    ArrayList<Nota> list = new ArrayList<Nota>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("vasca", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        Nota nota = new Nota(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getInt(4));
        list.add(nota);
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

The Class Nota has three String and one int.

Comment: If you have 4 columns, the index of the first is 0 and the last is 3 (not 4). You've said yourself you have 3 strings and 1 int so why are you trying to get 3 strings and 2 ints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method I prefer to use over hardcoding index is to user the `Cursor.getColumnIndex(String name)` function. Try changing it to this:

```
Nota nota = new Nota(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("integerColumn")),
   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstStringColumn")),
   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("secondStringColumn")),
   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("thirdStringColumn")));
```

This way you're much less likely to have this error, or worry about typographical errors; Especially if your column names are saved as variables.

Comment: Thanks, but not I get:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: That likely means one of your column names is incorrect. If the column name can't be found, it will return -1. @LeonardoShofflen

Comment: I took the id, because it should not be taken?

Answer (score 0):

You have four columns are you are trying to get values from five columns. you say one int an three string but you are fetching data from two int's Replace the following line :

```
Nota nota = new Nota(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getInt(4));

       With this

Nota nota = new Nota(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
```

Hope this might help you.